# django admin: queryset filter not working

Tags: django, postgresql, filter

I have the following class in my admin site:

```
class MyClassAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    options = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=MyClass.objects.filter(is_default=True), widget=FilteredSelectMultiple("verbose name", is_stacked=False))
```

In my understanding, this should return only objects for which `MyClass.is_default` is `True`.

EDIT
The `MyClass` model only has:

```
class MyClass(models.Model):
    is_default = models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text="is default")        
    name = models.CharField(help_text="the name of this", max_length=50)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

However, what happens is I get all objects of `MyClass`. Only 2 are set to `True`! That's really weird to me....

django 1.7.7

Comment: Can you add your models?

Comment: P.S. previously the field was called "default", which I thought might conflict...so I just renamed it to is_default and made migrations

Comment: What are you trying to achieve in your model admin? It's a bit unclear why you have the `options` variable in the model admin.

Comment: indeed @RodXavier that looks odd. I just need to list all MyClass objects which have is_default to True, and be able to add and remove new MyClass instances. I believe 'options' is from copy-paste...basically it is the list of the filtered objects! How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to only show objects where `is_default=True`, you can override the `queryset` method in your model admin.

```
class MyClassAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):    
    def queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(MyClassAdmin, self).queryset(request)
        return qs.filter(is_default=True)
```

**Update:**

As @pawel commented, the `queryset()` method was renamed to `get_queryset()` from Django 1.6.

Comment: In django 1.6 it was renamed to `get_queryset`

Comment: It does not work for Django 1.11.20. get_queryset() is executed but it's result is completely ignored. The assigned model displays all data from the table, it does not respect get_querytest()   (I use admin.TabularInline)